# User input PC name inserted into Windows CMD shutdown command via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, os.system

I'm looking to find out how I get the `pc_name` I type at the prompt inserted into the end of the `os.system` reboot command? or if I'm even on the right track. See below for example.

```
import os

pc_name = input ('Please enter the PC name to reboot: ')

os.system('shutdown /r /f /t 0 /m  <need pc_name here> ')
```

Just don't want to keep typing out the whole `shutdown` command in CMD every time.

Comment: `os.system('shutdown /r /f /t 0 /m  %s' % pc_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.format()` for string formatting.

eg. `os.system('shutdown /r /f /t 0 /m {}'.format(pc_name))`